# threes shader won't compile- various errors

Tags: three.js

So I am trying to load an image.  Originally it is out of S3/Cloudfront but im discovering that its not even working locally.

```
    var imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    imageTexture.load('/mypicture.jpg');

    imageTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
             map:imageTexture
    });
    img.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
three.js:18053 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders  
ERROR: 0:269: 'mapTexelToLinear' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:269: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:269: 'assign' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'highp 4-component vector of float'
```

When I use this

```
var imageTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/mypicture');
```

It works but when I try and load in image on CloudFront I get CORS errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the loader to the shader, not a texture.
The THREE.TextureLoader() load() function returns a texture.
Try something like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load('/mypicture.jpg');

texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
         map:texture
});
img.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: That I was.  Now fixed. Thanks!